# how to do mysql UPDATE with multiple arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large list of data I am trying to update

when I do an insert I first list the columns then put each array into a list with values

such as

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO customer (last_name, first_name, street_num, street_name, city, state, zip, phone,UUID,manager_UUID,points) VALUES(";
```

then for each item

```
$sql_query .= implode("),(", $rows);
                $sql_query .= ")";
```

I would like to do the same model for UPDATING data, but all the examples are usually column=data, column=data

is there a way to do

```
$sql_query = "UPDATE customer SET (last_name, first_name, street_num, street_name, city, state, zip, phone,UUID,manager_UUID,points) VALUES(";
```

then for each item

```
$sql_query .= implode("),(", $rows);
                $sql_query .= ")";
```

then at the end

```
$sql_query .= "WHERE column=condition";
```

Comment: implode("),(", $rows); will not prepare a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate solution would be to store the field names in an array and then process it.

Example:

```
$fieldString = 'last_name, first_name, street_num, street_name, city, state, zip, phone,UUID,manager_UUID,points';
$fieldList = explode(',',$fieldString);

//considering you have values stored in $rows array.

// Exit if $fieldlist does NOT match $rows
if (count($fieldList) != count($rows)){
   die; //or handle exception
}


// INSERT statement:

$sql_query = 'INSERT INTO customer ('.implode(',',$fieldList).)' VALUES ('.implode(',',$rows).') LIMIT 1';

// UPDATE statement:
$parameters = array();
for($offset=0;$offset<count($fieldList);$offset++){
    $parameters[] = $fieldList[$offset].' = '.$rows[$offset];
}

$sql_query = 'UPDATE customer SET '.implode(',',$parameters).' WHERE column=condition LIMIT 1';
```